# how can i delete a folder that created because of the program using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

I am makeing a python program using instabot and it automatically creat a folder name config.how can i delete that folder?

i am trying to delete that folder or my program not creat any of the folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module in Python to delete a folder. The os.rmdir() function can be used to delete an empty folder, and the shutil.rmtree() function can be used to delete a folder and its contents.